# Client threads and server, server displays client 1's message, then client 2's message, then 1 etc

Tags: java, multithreading, server, client

Question: Basically for say two clients, the server displays messages from the first client, then the second client in succession without displaying multiple messages typed from first client then say one message from the second client.

Expected result: Able to send as many messages as possible on one client followed by a different number of messages on second client.

Steps taken to attempt to solve problem:

1. Looked at a few sites on deadlocks, not sure if this is the same thing.
2. Tried changing the client to getting the inputstream first then the outputstream second, the server the other way around
3. Looked at getting rid of .filter on the lambda syntax

Steps to reproduce problem:

1. Load up server
2. Load up client 1
3. Load up client 2
4. Message on client 1
5. Message on client 1
6. Message on client 2
7. As a result only one message is displayed from each client

⠀

```
public class PrintLine extends Thread {

    private ArrayList<ClientThread> al;
    private Integer count;

    public PrintLine(ArrayList<ClientThread> al, Integer count) {
        this.al = al;
        this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean done = false;
        List<ClientThread> lines = new ArrayList<ClientThread>();
        while (!done) {
            al.stream().filter(x -> x.sInput == x.sInput).map(x -> x.getSInput()).forEach(sInput -> {
                try {
                    System.out.println(sInput.readUTF());
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(PrintLine.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

GitHub link for project: https://github.com/Runite618/ChatRoomVers2/commits/multiThreading

Thanks for reading and for any answers.

Matthew.

Comment: So only if a message is available from all clients, should a next round of messages be printed?

Comment: So say client 1 enters 2 messages, client 2 enters 1 message, server will only show first message from client 1 and the message from client 2.

Answer (score 0):

Posting this in case it helps someone else.

I solved by creating a separate thread of execution for each client in terms of the PrintLine class and now messages can be executed from each client independently of each other.

Matt.